# Overlay an image with Pin maps on WP8

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, dictionary

I would like to create a map from an Image I have and be able to place pin maps over it like the way it works with MapOverlay to display pin on a Map Control.

So the pin maps would have the same position on the image when zooming or scrolling.

Any idea how to proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by creating a map from an image?

Comment: I meant, I have an image that is a map of somewhere(museum, shop,etc...) and I would like to use that image like a Map. So i can scroll, zoom.